# How to broadcast message with Bukkit?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

In a Bukkit plugin, there's option to send message directly to player like this:

```
p.sendMessage(message);
```

Is there an option to send the message to all online players, "broadcasting" the message to everyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that `Bukkit.broadcastMessage(message);` records a message also on `Console`. You do not actually need that in most of cases.

You can do a simple `for` loop:

```
for (Player player : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
    player.sendMessage("It works!");
}
```

Or if you want you can just use

`Bukkit.broadcastMessage("It works too, but for console & players!");`

Comment: That's great thanks! :) i was looking for Bukkit.broadcastMessage("It works too, but for console & players"!); :P

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is. You can use

```
Bukkit.broadcastMessage(String message);
```

to send a message to all players online, or use

```
Bukkit.broadcast(String message, String permission);
```

to send a message to all users who have the specified permission.

Comment: `Bukkit.broadcastMessage()` is not sending to all players online, but for all instances connected, also to console.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Player player : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
player.sendMessage("It works!");
} `is the code?`
[youtube.com/?Feature=youtu.be][1]
[blank] [2]
```